# Can I annotate frames in backwards in CVAT?

Tags: image, video, annotations, frames, cvat

I have frames with several objects, by the end they become large, but at the beginning it is impossible to see. Is it possible in CVAT to annotate objects from the last frame to the first, like in VIAME DAVE?

I tried renaming files/frames through the program Advanced Renamer, but this is an unnecessary action.Plus, annotations cannot be applied to the same frames in the original sequence.